# Rails undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm earning rails with the guidebook, but some code does not run as expected (use Rails 4.2.6, but book was written about older version). Appreciate if you can help me.

When i load pages of any of my objects (Ads) - i see nice page with object parameters, but when I load page with list of objects - I get

```
NoMethodError in Ads#index
Showing /home/mei33/mebay/app/views/ads/index.html.erb where line #11 raised:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

<ul>
    <% for ad in @ads %>
        <li><a href="/ads/<%= @ad.id %>"><%= @ad.name %></a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

my ads_controler.rb looks like that:

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
        @ads = Ad.all
    end
end
```

tried to add this line of code, but not helped:

```
def new
 @ad = Ad.new
end
```

maybe there is something I cannot notice? some mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call as `ad.id` not `@ad.id`:

```
<ul>
    <% for ad in @ads %>
        <li><a href="/ads/<%= ad.id %>"><%= ad.name %></a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Or:

```
<ul>
    <% @ads.each do |ad| %>
        <li><a href="/ads/<%= ad.id %>"><%= ad.name %></a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank's man! what a stupid mistake and how attentive are you!